# Android XML static button position in front of image with multiple device

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I have Android XML to set up seven button position in front of image at virtual instrument. In tab 7" working fine, but in other devices with other size, the button position wasn't in tone hole in virtual instrument.

My Android XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.serunekaleebeta.Main"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/serune"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
   />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnDo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMi"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnRe"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFa"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnMi"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSol"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnFa"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLa"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSol"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSi"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLa"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:color="#66FF0000"
    android:alpha="0.15"
    />
```

ImageView of virtual instrument: http://iloveaceh.org/labdigital/serune.png

Comment: so what do you really want?

Comment: Use separate layouts for larger and smaller screens

Comment: @Elltz i want my layout adaptive with any devices size, not only in 7" but also in 4", 4.5", or others can work fine..